# How do I use CSS inside a PHP While Loop to display data?

Tags: php, html, css

I already have the CSS Layout in a .css file.

Here is my php line of code

```
$display_block .= "<div id=\"contentTitle\">$title</div> <div id=\"contentDescription\">$description</div>"

echo $display_block;
```

For some reason, it isn't recognizing the "id" part of my code so my text is not being formatted!

Comment: From what you've posted, if you're seeing the text, the divs should also have the appropriate IDs (`#contentTitle`, and `#contentDescription`). make sure that your CSS file is linked as a stylesheet to the page you are viewing.

Comment: Your both ids are getting proper, please check if you have linked css file correctly.

Comment: You may find that a debugger such as Firebug will help you greatly with debugging this issue.

Comment: Please post your CSS code. It's hard to tell what CSS you are using. Would be much easier if we had something more to look at,

Comment: Also, make sure that you initialize  the `$display_block = '';` before attempting to concatenating content into it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! It turns out it was my CSS code actually! And the reason I am putting the "id" in the php code is because I am displaying a data report onto a webpage with a loop.

Comment: If your code is used in a loop then you should not use IDs. IDs should be unique on the page. Use classes instead (i.e. `.contentTitle` and `.contentDescription`).

Comment: why dont you tell displaying a data report onto a webpage with a loop. first place

Answer (score -1):

why dont you write like this it is easy to undestand.....

```
$title='aaa';
$description = '222';
$display_block = "<div id='contentTitle'>".$title."</div> <div id='contentDescription'>".$description."</div>";
echo $display_block;
```

output

```
<div id='contentTitle'>aaa</div> <div id='contentDescription'>222</div>
```

Comment: It still isn't recognizing the id part of the code. :( Maybe what i'm trying to do isn't possible?

Comment: r you want to add id as a variable

Answer (score -1):

Seems no wrong things of you code but,

Why you do not write like this:

```
<div id="contentTitle"><?php echo $title ?></div>
```

Comment: Use the comments for comments. Also, the result of your code is exactly the same as the OP's code.

Comment: It does not answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

please try this code 
if your css id =contentTitle,
if your css id =contentDescription
than this code run

```
$display_block .= "<div id='contentTitle'>$title</div> <div id='contentDescription'>$description</div>";
echo $display_block;
```

best of luck dear

Answer (score -2):

You can write like this-
$display_block .= "$title $description"

echo $display_block;

Comment: This is not what the OP is asking about. Please read the question before answering.